# Unhandled error during execution of mounted hook in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an app To Do List. Using button you add task and new task adds to the list of items with checkbox and delete button in front of each one. I want to save all value and marked info on page (store it) once page renewed using browser. When I`m using mounted and watch.There are 2 issues: 1)When I use CodePen or GitHub to view the site and app it shows nothing and in console.log:"Unhandled error during execution of mounted hook"; 2)In Visual Studio Code it shows everything on preview, but stores only value of input-not marked chekboxes. Please help to solve it. Below my code:

```js
Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return{
          placeholder: 'Start typing',
          inputvalue: '',
          notes: [],
          checked: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('note')) || [];
      },
      watch: {
            notes: {
                handler: function() {
                    localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(this.notes));
                },
                deep: true
            }
        },
    methods: {
        addnewtask(){
            if (this.inputvalue !== ''){
                this.notes.push(this.inputvalue)
                this.inputvalue=''
            }
        },
        removetask(index){
            if (confirm('Do you really want to delete?'))
            this.notes.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
}).mount(app)
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #030303;
    background: #3d5f82;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: solid;
}
.btn {
    color: #31d78c;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 99px;
    border: 1px solid #31d78c;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #fff;
}
.btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:rgb(231, 239, 235);
}
.btn.danger {
    color: #eb3c15;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 99px;
    border: 1px solid #eb3c15;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #fff;
}
.btn.danger:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:rgb(236, 219, 219);
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.form-control {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-control input,
.form-control select {
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    color: #2c3e50;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.card {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #fff;
}
.card.center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.list-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    transition: .22s all;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<style>
    [v-cloak] {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="app" v-cloak>
      <div class="card">
          <h1>To Do List</h1>
          <div class="form-control">
             <input
                 type="text" 
                 v-bind:placeholder="placeholder" 
                 v-model="inputvalue"
                 v-on:keypress.enter="addnewtask"
              />
              <button class="btn" v-on:click="addnewtask">Add Task</button>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <ul class="list" v-if="notes.length !== 0"...>
                <li class="list-item" v-for="(note, index) in notes" v-bind:key="note">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[note]"/>
                        <span :style="checked[note] ? 'text-decoration: line-through' : ''">
                            {{index+1}}) {{note}}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn danger" v-on:click="removetask(index)">Delete</button>
                </li>
                <hr />
                <li>
                    <strong>Total: {{notes.length}}</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div v-else>No task exist, please add first one.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script src="Vue3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no CodePen in the question. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask, sorry but I don`t know where it can be reproduced else-CodePen is free and easy to use online, please advise?

Comment: If you can reproduce it in codepen then consider providing a link to codepen

Answer (score 3):

Try adding JSON.parse in a try-catch block

```js
mounted() {
  try {
    this.notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('note'))
  } catch(e) {
    this.notes = []
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another error: Unhandled error during execution of watcher callback. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.getItem('note') || ''`